# Polynomials in Pari

Tags: polynomial-math, pari, pari-gp

I have some problems dealing with polynomials in Pari and finding the right commands in the documentation.

1. is it possible to define Polynomials with multiple variables, e.g. f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1
2. How can I evaluate a previously defined polynomial (by using Pol() ) at a specific value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use polynomials with multiple variables. For example `x^2 + y^2 - 1` is a polynomial in the variables `x` and `y`. Use `subst` to evaluate a polynomial at a specific value. For example, `subst(x^2 + y^2 - 1, y, 3)` gives `x^2 + 8`.

PARI assumes any undefined variables are polynomials. The above works because x and y have not been given another definition. For this reason it is best to avoid using x and y for other things. For example if you enter `x=5`, then `x` is defined to be 5 and will no longer be interpreted as a polynomial.

Now  `f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1` is not a polynomial, but rather a function definition with two formal arguments `x` and `y`. You can call `f` with the polynomial arguments `x` and `y` to get a polynomial and can also call `f` with other arguments. For example, `f(x,y)` returns the polynomial `x^2 + y^2 - 1` and  `f(x, 3)` returns `x^2 + 8`.

The purpose of `Pol()` is rather to convert something else such as a vector into  a polynomial. For example, `Pol([3,1,5])` gives `3*x^2 + x + 5`.

Comment: Thx for your answer. So if I want f to be a polynomial, i simply need to define it by f=x^2+y^2+1?

Comment: How can I evaluate a power series? I know that I can convert them to polynomials, but this gives only correct values for x close to 0

Answer (score 2):

PARI also does power series. For example `1/(1-x-x^2) + O(x^20)` is the power series expansion up to 20 terms. You need to specify the number of terms required (PARI does not expand infinitely). Use `Vec()` to convert into a vector. For example, `Vec(1/(1-x-x^2) + O(x^20))` gives the first 20 terms of the Fibonacci series.

Multivariate power series are also possible, but you need to be careful with variable priority. If you use `x` as the primary power series variable (indeterminate) and `y` as the secondary variable it will work. On the other hand if you want to use `z` as the primary variable and `t` as the secondary variable you may run into issues depending on which order `z` and `t` are first used. Priority of variables is a messy issue and is best avoided by knowing that `x` and `y` are predefined with `x` having higher priority than `y`.

(If you have more questions, please submit a new question - I don't really want this to become a blog on all PARI features!)

Comment: This is an answer to a comment. That comment should have been turned into a separate thread (Ask Question) instead.